# How to compare a template var in the html page in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a ionic beginner, and I really do not know how to compare a var in *ngIf.

I have a user class, and one of its atribute is averageRating, that is a Number. In my rating.page.html I can show it like this: 
`{{user.averageRating}}` but I want to show it in a more natural way, with stars.

I know I can not compare like this: `*ngIf="{{user.averageRating}}>=1"`

So I have try to declare a public ratingActual: Number in my class RatingPage in my rating.page.ts and asign value in the constructor:

`this.ratingActual = this.user.averageRate;`

And I do in my html:  `*ngIf="ratingActual>=1"`

But is not working. However if I change this.user.averageRate by a number it works.

I would like to understand wy is not working and find an solution, an easy one if it is posible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that variable `ratingActual` is greater than 1? What `console.log(ratingActual)` says to you? Did you tried `*ngIf="user.averageRating >= 1"`?

Comment: Hi Filipe, thanks for your answer. The problem is that `this.user.averageRate` has not value, so `ratingActual` has not value either. I supose, it must be related with  the moment the user is created.